# yii2 identity session expiry

Tags: php, yii2, identity, yii2-advanced-app

I am new to yii2 framework and I am facing a problem with the identity. when the session timeouts or when I change my user status to inactive I am getting an error of Trying to get property of non-object from the user component.

```
public function getName()
{
    return \Yii::$app->user->identity->username;
}
```

as I am retrieving this value in the header of the website, I want to redirect to login page instead of showing this error

Comment: Please share the behaviors() method from your controller for further assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As good practice you should use **Access Control Filters** in your controller. Please refer to this [link](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization) to get an idea on how to implement authorisation in your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

In Controller file you should put:

```
if (\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
   return $this->redirect(["site/login"]);
}
```

It's because "identity" is set only on users who are logged in..
So you can't access identity because he is guest..

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-user#$isGuest-detail